# Jupyter Kernel : Is there a way to rename them?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I mis-typed the name for the kernel while issuing:
python -m ipykernel install --name 
and the wrong name is showing up the Jupyter's "Change kernel" menu.  Is there a way to change just the name (without unstalling and installing it with the right name again)?  I could not find where Jupyter is storing the names of the installed kernels.  That could perhaps be edited?
Thanks, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `kernelspec` command to get information about the installed Kernels for your installation.

The command `jupyter kernelspec list` will provide you a list of the installed Kernels, something like:

```
Available kernels:
  python2          /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  redisworkshop    /Users/tague/Library/Jupyter/kernels/RedisWorkshop
  bash             /Users/tague/Library/Jupyter/kernels/bash
```

The display name for a kernel is found in the **kernel.json** file in the corresponding directory for the kernel.
Edit the `display_name` property in the **kernel.json** file and it will change the display name next time you start Jupyter.

Comment: I missed the answer my first pass - you need to change the file named `kernel.json` located inside the kernel path.

Comment: Does that work for your python2 kernel as well? I don't find a **kernel.json** for the default kernel.