# How to Change Jupyter Notebook Kernel Display Name

Tags: python, user-interface, kernel, jupyter-notebook

May I ask how to change the kernel display name from `Python [defaul]` to `Python 2.7.12` for example?

I've been trying to modify the kernel.json file, particularly chaning the "display_name" from `Python 2` to `Python 2.7.12` But whenever I reopen the user interface through command `ipython notebook`, it never changes to what I want.

[image]

To clarify the possible duplicate with previous question: I did try what it suggests to do as I describe in the question. Unfortunately, it just doesn’t work. It would be nice if someone who does make this change successfully could share how they do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Kernel : Is there a way to rename them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085233/jupyter-kernel-is-there-a-way-to-rename-them)

Comment: I did try what it suggests to do as I describe in the question. Unfortunately, it just doesn’t work. It would be nice if someone who does make this change successfully could share how they do.

Comment: What errors do you get? Why do you say it is not working. Please give more information.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Not working means that after I changed the kernel file (particularly "display_name"), whenever I reopen the jupyter notebook, the display name of the python doesn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Linux Mint 17. From a terminal I ran:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

I have a Python 2 kernel listed:

```
  python2        /home/matthew/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
```

I edited the file:

```
/home/matthew/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json
```

Changing line 2 from:

```
 "display_name": "Python 2",
```

To:

```
"display_name": "Python 2 test",
```

I killed the jupyter notebook tabs in chrome, then stopped and restarted the jupyter notebook server.

Now, instead of seeing 'Python 2' as the kernel name, I see 'Python 2 test'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. And the reason I failed previously, even following your instruction, is that my Anaconda has some corrupt files that my anaconda navigator couldn't be opened. Now I reinstall anaconda, your suggestion actually works well.

Answer (score 0):

OK，I don't know how you add the kernel.
I add the kernel like this, and it does work.
first, make sure you have installed **ipykernel**;
then run the command:

`python -m ipykernel install  --name kernelname`